# How to shrink or fit video on mobile devices in a two bootstrap columns setup?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, video

I have two columns in Bootstrap 4, one column has a video and the other has text or other type of content:

```css
#video-meta-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="vidcontainer" class="col-sm-8">
      <video controls>  
        <p>Your browser does not support video.</p>
       <source src="http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4"> 
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
      <div style="" class="row" id="vid-content-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="video-meta-content">
          few paragraoh of text here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The video size is 720 x 406. It displays correctly in desktop and landscape tablet but on phone the video is showing in a 720px wide frame, part of which is hidden due to the small screen. Some of the content column also goes on top of the video instead of stacking below the video column if screen is too small to fit both columns in one row.

I would like the video to shrink to fit screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to getting the video to adapt to the available width is to add the following lines of css:

```
video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will restrict the video to the width of its container while the height will automatically adjust to keep the aspect ratio. The video will never grow larger than it's actual size (`1920px` in the example below) so if the width of `#vidcontainer` is smaller than the video the video will constrain itself to that width, if `#vidcontainer` is bigger then the video will be its usual size.

You can see this by putting the below Stack Snippet into Full Page and changing the width of the browser window.

```css
#video-meta-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="vidcontainer" class="col-sm-8">
      <video controls>    
        <p>Your browser does not support video.</p>
        <source src="http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4">     
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
      <div style="" class="row" id="vid-content-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="video-meta-content">
          few paragraoh of text here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution, just that little change fixed all the issues across all device types! thank u for great explanation too!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Add class col-xs-4, col-xs-8, col-xs-12 in addition to existing classes. col-xs-* is for small devices like mobile

Comment: some one had posted detailed answer here as I was reading through it it was deleted please repost it

Answer (score -1):

Add class "col" in addition to "col-sm-8" and "col-sm-8".
For eg.,

```
class="col col-sm-8"
class="col col-sm-4"
```

By using ".col" bootstrap automatically handle the layout.